# sql - Unpivot a join between two tables with the same column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with unpivoting the results of a join between two tables. The two tables are defined as:

```
create table scores_jan (
   id number
 , test_1 number
 , test_2 number
 , test_3 number
 );

create table scores_feb (
   id number
 , test_1 number
 , test_2 number
 , test_3 number
 );

insert into scores_jan values (1, 50, 60, 70);
insert into scores_feb values (1, 55, 65, 75);
commit;
```

I want to unpivot this to get a row for each ID/test combination, to achieve the result:

```
ID    TEST_NUMBER    JAN_SCORE    FEB_SCORE
1     test_1         50           55
1     test_2         60           65
1     test_3         70           75
```

If I write the unpivot without specifying the columns I'm interested in, it looks like this:

```
select *
  from scores_jan j
  join scores_feb f
    on j.id = f.id
unpivot ( (jan_score, feb_score) for test_name in ( (test_1, test_1) as 'test_1'
                                                  , (test_2, test_2) as 'test_2'
                                                  , (test_3, test_3) as 'test_3'
                                                  )
        )
```

This generates the error ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

If I try to write it with specifying the columns to use, it looks like this:

```
select *
  from scores_jan j
  join scores_feb f
    on j.id = f.id
unpivot ( (jan_score, feb_score) for test_name in ( (j.test_1, f.test_1) as 'test_1'
                                                  , (j.test_2, f.test_2) as 'test_2'
                                                  , (j.test_3, f.test_3) as 'test_3'
                                                  )
        )
```

This generates the error ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here

Is there a way to get this unpivot to work? I could put one of the tables into a subquery, but it seems pretty suboptimal to use a subquery just for changing the alias of a column.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to achieve.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The expected results have been added.

Comment: @spielchecker - Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff oracle12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      *

from        (         select 'JAN_SCORE' as mth,id,test_1,test_2,test_3 from scores_jan s
            union all select 'FEB_SCORE'       ,id,test_1,test_2,test_3 from scores_feb s 
            ) unpivot (score for test in (test_1,test_2,test_3))
              pivot (max(score) for mth in ('JAN_SCORE','FEB_SCORE'))

order by    test
```

---

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | TEST   | JAN_SCORE | FEB_SCORE |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | TEST_1 | 50        | 55        |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | TEST_2 | 60        | 65        |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | TEST_3 | 70        | 75        |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What's the PIVOT for? I don't see it in the question. Otherwise, +1 for realizing that a join is not needed; in my book **THIS** is the correct answer.

Comment: @mathguy - check the requested result - a column for JAN and a column for FEB

Comment: This would appear to answer the OP's clarified question.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that the column names are same for the two tables and if you try to use aliases in the UNPIVOT, it'll give error saying - *simple names expected*.

In Oracle 12c+, use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select j.id, x.*
  from scores_jan j
  join scores_feb f
    on j.id = f.id
outer apply (
    select 'test_1' test_name, j.test_1 jan_score, f.test_1 feb_score from dual union all
    select 'test_2', j.test_2, f.test_2 from dual union all
    select 'test_3', j.test_3, f.test_3 from dual
) x
```

In order versions, do the join in subquery, do aliasing and then use `UNPIVOT`:

```
select * 
from (      
    select 
        j.id,
        j.test_1 j_test_1,
        j.test_2 j_test_2,
        j.test_3 j_test_3,
        f.test_1 f_test_1,
        f.test_2 f_test_2,
        f.test_3 f_test_3
    from scores_jan j
    join scores_feb f
        on j.id = f.id
    ) 
unpivot (
    (jan_score, feb_score) 
    for test_name in (
        (j_test_1, f_test_1) as 'test_1',
        (j_test_2, f_test_2) as 'test_2',
        (j_test_3, f_test_3) as 'test_3'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "unpivot" is the right approach.  If you have only one row per `id` in each table, then use `union all` or a similar approach.  Here is the idea:

```
select j.id, j.test_1 as test from scores_jan union all
select j.id, j.test_2 as test from scores_jan union all
select j.id, j.test_3 as test from scores_jan union all
select f.id, f.test_1 as test from scores_feb union all
select f.id, f.test_2 as test from scores_feb union all
select f.id, f.test_3 as test from scores_feb ;
```

You should also recognize that using separate tables for separate months is a really *bad* idea.  You should be storing all the data in a single table, with a column specifying the month.

Comment: `UNPIVOT` is, absolutely, the right answer - it requires reading each table just once. This `UNION ALL` approach reads each table three times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you saw, is the ambiguous column names. There are really two problems. One is the `id` column. You can deal with it by using a different join syntax - instead of `on j.id = f.id` write `using(id)`. Check the documentation for this join syntax if you are not familiar with it.

However, the ambiguity of the `test_1` column name can't be addressed this way, and as you saw, you can't use table qualifiers with `unpivot`.

The correct solution, in this situation, is to have the entire join as a subquery (not just one of the tables); `select from ( join subquery ) unpivot...`

Of course, you could change the column names in the tables (to `j_test_1`, `f_test_1` etc.) but that may be too much trouble. If you go that way, the `id` column name should still be the same in both tables, and you would still need the `using(id)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

P.s.

Could also be solved like this

```
select      id,test,jan_score,feb_score

from                scores_jan j
            join    (select  id as fid,test_1 as f1,test_2 as f2,test_3 as f3 
                     from    scores_feb
                     ) f
            on      j.id = f.fid
            unpivot ((jan_score,feb_score) for (test) in 
               ((test_1,f1) as 'test_1',(test_2,f2) as 'test_2',(test_3,f3) as 'test_3')) u

order by    test
```